# How do I catch a psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation error in a Python (Flask) app?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a small Python web app (written in Flask) that uses sqlalchemy to persist data to the database.  When I try to insert a duplicate row, an exception is raised, something like this:

```
(psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uix_my_column"
```

I would like to wrap the exception and re-raise my own so I can add my own logging and messaging that is specific to that particular error.  This is what I tried (simplified):

```
from db import DbApi
from my_exceptions import BadRequest
from psycopg2.errors import UniqueViolation # <-- this does not exist!

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DbApi() 

    def create(self, data: dict) -> MyRecord:
        try:
            with self.db.session_local(expire_on_commit=False) as session:
                my_rec = MyRecord(**data)
                session.add(my_rec)
                session.commit()
                session.refresh(my_rec)
                return my_rec
        except UniqueViolation as e:
            raise BadRequest('A duplicate record already exists')
```

But this fails to trap the error because `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation` isn't actually a class name (!).

In PHP, this would be as easy as catching copy/pasting the classname of the exception, but in Python, this is much more obfuscated.

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769988/django-python-catch-mysql-integrityerror), but it didn't deal with this specific use-case and (importantly), it did not clarify how one can identify the root exception class name.

How does one find out what exception is actually being raised? Why does Python hide this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044922/how-to-access-psycopg2-error-wrapped-in-sqlalchemy-error/56050741#56050741

Comment: Sqlalchemy wraps the underlying dbapi error, so you need to catch the sqlalchemy error, not the dbapi one, then you can inspect the original error through the SQLAlchemy one.

Comment: Also I answered this recently which is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766555/6560549

Comment: Thanks.  I am, however, still very unclear on how to identify the classname of the original exception I'm attempting to trap.  Is Googling the psycopg2 docs the only way to figure out what exception was thrown? Why isn't this more transparent in Python?

Comment: Have done my best to explain in below answer, happy to elaborate on any points there, just ask in the comments.

Answer (score 54):

The error that you have posted in your question isn't the error that has been raised. The full error message is:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "model_name_key"
```

The key part being the SQLAlchemy error which you've chosen to omit for some reason. SQLAlchemy catches the original error, wraps it in it's own error and raises that.

> but in Python, this is much more obfuscated... Why does Python hide this?

This isn't obfuscation, nothing is hidden, the behavior is documented, specific to the frameworks that you are using and is not enforced by the Python language. SQLAlchemy is an abstraction library and if it were to raise exceptions specific to the underlying dpapi adapter, it would significantly reduce the portability of code written within it.

From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html?highlight=exceptions#dbapi-errors):

> SQLAlchemy does not generate these exceptions directly. Instead, they
>   are intercepted from the database driver and wrapped by the
>   SQLAlchemy-provided exception DBAPIError, however the messaging within
>   the exception is generated by the driver, not SQLAlchemy.

Exceptions raised by the dbapi layer are wrapped in a subclass of the [sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/exceptions.html?highlight=exceptions#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError), where it is noted:

> The wrapped exception object is available in the `orig` attribute.

So it's very straightforward to catch the SQLAlchemy exception and inspect the original exception, which is an instance of `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation`, as you'd expect. However, unless your error handling is very specific to the type raised by the dbapi layer, I'd suggest that inspecting the underlying type might be unnecessary as the SQLAlchemy exception that is raised will provide enough runtime information to do what you have to do.

Here is an example script that raises a `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError`, catches it, inspects the underlying exception through the `orig` attribute and raises an alternate, locally-defined exception.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from psycopg2.errors import UniqueViolation


engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://some-user:mysecretpassword@localhost:5432/some-user")

Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class BadRequest(Exception):
    pass


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    s = Session()
    s.add(Model(name="a"))
    s.commit()
    s.add(Model(name="a"))
    try:
        s.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        assert isinstance(e.orig, UniqueViolation)  # proves the original exception
        raise BadRequest from e
```

And that raises:

```sh
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "model_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(a) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO model (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING model.id]
[parameters: {'name': 'a'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    raise BadRequest from e
__main__.BadRequest
```

Comment: Yikes, that omission wasn't on purpose -- for some reason, I'm not seeing `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` in my logs which makes me wonder what our custom logger is doing.

Comment: That's because it probably wasn't there just like mine. People on the internet just love assuming malice though.

Comment: The following import statement does not work. `from psycopg2.errors import UniqueViolation`.

Comment: @Jwely Yes, it does. I just tested on latest PyPI version (2.8.5).

Comment: @SuperShoot. There is clearly some environmental issue. On two different environments installed from the same requirements, one allows the import and the other does not. Identical versions of python, psycopg2, and postgres. I'll dig deeper into it to add more  useful information, may open a new question.

Comment: @Jwely I am having the same issue. psycopg2.errors is a mostly empty file

Answer (score 23):

I have a slightly different answer that avoids looking up the specific numerical error code. Simply import the constant that defines `UNIQUE_VIOLATION`:

```
from psycopg2.errorcodes import UNIQUE_VIOLATION
from psycopg2 import errors
```

Then use the error lookup function:

```
except errors.lookup(UNIQUE_VIOLATION) as e:
```

Solved the issue for me. You can import other error code constants as necessary.

Answer (score 10):

According to psycopg2 [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#dbapi-exceptions):

> In compliance with the DB API 2.0, the module makes informations about errors available through the following exceptions:
>
> **exception psycopg2.Error**
>
> Exception that is the base class of all other error exceptions. You can use this to catch all errors with one single except statement. Warnings are not considered errors and thus not use this class as base. It is a subclass of the Python StandardError (Exception on Python 3).

Thus, the proper way to catch the exceptions is:

```py
try:
    # your stuff here
except psycopg2.Error as e:
    # get error code
    error = e.pgcode
    # then do something.
```

Yours in particular is error 23505 according to the [ErrCodes Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html#ERRCODES-TABLE)

Answer (score 8):

For a quick reference to **how to import the psycopg2 UniqueViolation** (or any other error)
with some quick *recipes*.

### 1) Import  UniqueViolation

```
   import traceback   # Used for printing the full traceback | Better for debug.
   from psycopg2 import errors

   UniqueViolation = errors.lookup('23505')  # Correct way to Import the psycopg2 errors

   # ...... Code ....

    try:
        db.commit()           
    except UniqueViolation as err:
        traceback.print_exc()
        db.rollback()            

    # ...... Code ....
```

---

### 2) Import  IntegrityError

UniqueViolation base-exception is actually IntegrityError , so for a broader error catch
(for whatever reason, normally is not recommended, but rule are meant to be broken)

```
   import traceback   # Used for printing the full traceback | Better for debug.
   from psycopg2._psycopg import IntegrityError

   # ...... Code ....

    try:
        db.commit()           
    except IntegrityError as err:
        traceback.print_exc()
        db.rollback()            

    # ...... Code ....
```

---

### 3) Source Code

The **psycopg2** errors module is found here --> `/psycopg2/errors.py`, and is actually like a *gateway* for the real error code list.

Here you can see the function used to call the correct error by given code:

```
    #
    # NOTE: the exceptions are injected into this module by the C extention.
    #
    
    
    def lookup(code):
        """Lookup an error code and return its exception class.
    
        Raise `!KeyError` if the code is not found.
        """
        from psycopg2._psycopg import sqlstate_errors   # avoid circular import
        return sqlstate_errors[code]
```

But the really juicy stuff are found here ---> `\psycopg2\_psycopg\__init__.py`
Once here find the variable `sqlstate_errors` which is a dict containing the codes as value and the actual error as Note, here is a small snippet (is pretty big):

```
    sqlstate_errors = {
        '02000': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.NoData'>"
        '02001': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.NoAdditionalDynamicResultSetsReturned'>"
        '03000': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.SqlStatementNotYetComplete'>"
        '08000': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.ConnectionException'>"
        '08001': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.SqlclientUnableToEstablishSqlconnection'>"
        '08003': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.ConnectionDoesNotExist'>"
        '08004': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.SqlserverRejectedEstablishmentOfSqlconnection'>"
        '08006': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.ConnectionFailure'>"
        '08007': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.TransactionResolutionUnknown'>"
        '08P01': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.ProtocolViolation'>"
 # -------- Lots of lines ---------- # 
        '23503': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation'>"
        # There you are!!!
        '23505': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation'>" 
        # ---------------- 
        '23514': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.CheckViolation'>"
        '23P01': None, # (!) real value is "<class 'psycopg2.errors.ExclusionViolation'>"
```

---

### 4) Documentation

- [psycopg.org | SQLSTATE   Exception](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/errors.html#sqlstate-exception-classes)
- [postgresq | PostgreSQL Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html#ERRCODES-TABLE)

Answer (score 2):

The answers above didn't work for me for some reason, but this did:

```
from asyncpg.exceptions import UniqueViolationError
...
except exc.IntegrityError as e:
   if e.orig.__cause__.__class__ == UniqueViolationError:
       # raise some error specific to unique violation errors
```

Comment: This is only for folks who are using `asyncpg`, which is built on top of `psycopg`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this nowadays (2023) seems to be:

```py
from sqlalchmey.exc import IntegrityError
from psycopg2.errors import UniqueViolation

try:
    <something>
except IntegrityError as e:
    if isinstance(e.orig, UniqueViolation):
        # here, you've caught specifically a UniqueViolation
        <do something>
    else:
        # here, you know the error is something else, so you could reraise
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from db import DbApi
from my_exceptions import BadRequest
from psycopg2 import errors

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DbApi() 

    def create(self, data: dict) -> MyRecord:
        try:
            with self.db.session_local(expire_on_commit=False) as session:
                my_rec = MyRecord(**data)
                session.add(my_rec)
                session.commit()
                session.refresh(my_rec)
                return my_rec
        except errors.lookup("23505"):
            raise BadRequest('A duplicate record already exists')
```

I get a `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation` error. How do I handle it ?

please refer to https://www.psycopg.org/docs/errors.html for more details about how to handle psycopg2 errors

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem in this way:

```
from asyncpg.exceptions import UniqueViolationError

    try:
        user.id = await self.database.execute(query)
    except UniqueViolationError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail="User with this credentials already exist")
```